# How can I change formulas to static values after the formula has calculated the value?

Tags: vba, static, data-analysis

I have an inventory sheet setup where a user is scanning part numbers into a sheet and a "date scanned" column will display the current date. The formula itself is working fine as it is showing the "today()" function to display the date. However, once the spreadsheet is open, the values now show today's date rather than the original scan in date (because the formula recalculates the date).

I've figured out how to change the formulas to values but I'm struggling with getting the timing right.

The below code does what is intended; it takes a look at all rows with a formula and converts them to values. The problem however, is that if a row does not have a value in it yet, just a formula, it will replace the formula with a blank.

I would like to make the code more robust and only change once a value has been determined by the formula (i.e. once a user scans in a part number). If a part number has not been scanned in, I would like the formula to stay in the column until done so by the user.

```
Sub makeStatic()
'
'Convert date formula to a static value
'

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:E" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    If rng.HasFormula Then
        rng.Formula = rng.Value
    End If

Next rng

End Sub
```

I figured this would be a combination of an if statement paired with an event handler but I haven't been able to decipher the best way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no need to loop, just: `ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:E" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:E" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Value` and the whole range will turn into values.

Comment: How do you determine that "a value has been determined by the formula"?

Comment: Maybe the below line of code will clarify; it shows the formula and the conditions it needs to execute. This is the order of operations I'd like to occur: 1 - formula in cell, 2 - user inputs part number, 3 - formula runs based on user input and returns value, 4 - convert value to value (which above code does). If the part number is blank (no input from user), keep formula in cell until step 2 is satisfied.

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(RC[-4]),ISBLANK(RC[-2])),"""",TODAY())"

Comment: @Damian - the intention is not to convert the entire range to values. Only the cells where the formula has returned a value. If formula does not return a value, keep formula.

Comment: `If Len(rng.Value)>0 Then rng.Value = rng.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a solution that gives you the result you are asking for, but in another way than you were sketching.

Let's consider your worksheet having the `Part number` in column `A` and `Date scanned` in column `B`. Both column `A` and `B` are empty, until the scanner enters the part number to column `A`. To react on a change in a cell in the `A` and end up with current date in `B`, you can write the following VBA function:

```
Option Explicit 'Excel worksheet change event for range A1 to A10

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Cells(1, 2).Value = Date
  End If
End Sub
```

Of course you would change the range as needed.